# Console.writeline() instantiates an object with winUSB?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, winusb

I'm using WinUSB in C# to talk with a PIC4550 using Bulk Transfers, and am running into a bit of a strange problem.

The current code works correctly, but still includes a few debug Console.Write() lines that I'd like to remove because they're cluttering up the code.  Removing them and stepping through the code with the debugger also works correctly.

Unfortunately, when I remove the debug lines, the code stops working. The 'result' byte array returns as null, and throws a null reference exception.

What's going on here?

```
    public static ulong GetBulkData(Device d, ref byte[] result)
    {

        byte _inPipe = 0x81;
        ulong bufferlength = 64;


        NativeOverlapped gOverlapped = new NativeOverlapped();
        GCHandle pinnedOverlap = new GCHandle();

        gOverlapped.InternalLow = IntPtr.Zero;
        gOverlapped.InternalHigh = IntPtr.Zero;
        gOverlapped.OffsetLow = 0;
        gOverlapped.OffsetHigh = 0;
        gOverlapped.EventHandle = Win32.CreateEvent(IntPtr.Zero, true, false, IntPtr.Zero);
        pinnedOverlap = GCHandle.Alloc(gOverlapped, GCHandleType.Pinned);



        ulong lengthtransferred = 0;
        Array.Clear(result, 0, result.Length);
        GCHandle pinnedBuffer = GCHandle.Alloc(result, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Win32.WinUsb_ReadPipe(d._handle, _inPipe, pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject(), bufferlength, ref lengthtransferred, pinnedOverlap.AddrOfPinnedObject());
        int hr = Win32.GetLastError();

        bool bResult = (hr == 0);
        pinnedOverlap.Free();
        if (bResult)
        {
            foreach (byte b in result)
                Console.Write(" " + b);
            return lengthtransferred;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("USB Error Code " + hr);
            uint pLength = 0;
            // Deal with the error code
            switch (hr)
            {
                case Win32.ERROR_IO_PENDING:
                    // Asynchronous I/O is still in progress... wait for it to complete
                    int evt = Win32.WaitForSingleObject(gOverlapped.EventHandle, 10);
                    switch (evt)
                    {
                        case Win32.WAIT_OBJECT_0:

                            // I/O completed.
                            // Check on the results of the asynchronous read and update the nBytesRead
                            bResult = Win32.WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult(d._handle, pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject(), out pLength, true);
                            if (bResult)
                            {

                                // Success
                                Console.WriteLine("USB overlap received");
                            }

                            break;

                        case Win32.WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                        default:

                            // I/O error or timeout.  Cancel outstanding I/O.
                            Win32.CancelIo(d._handle);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

            }
            pinnedBuffer.Free();
            return pLength;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `GCHandle pinnedOverlap = new GCHandle();` is pointless, you just overwrite it, either do `GCHandle pinnedOverlap;` or just declare it further down `GCHandle  pinnedOverlap = GCHandle.Alloc(gOverlapped, GCHandleType.Pinned);`

Comment: This change makes for better code, but doesn't solve the problem I'm having.

Comment: That is why I posted it as a comment, not a answer. I don't know the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may do with the following line :

```
foreach (byte b in result)
            Console.Write(" " + b);
        return lengthtransferred;
```

Currently you are only writing to the console in the foreach, you may need to remove the foreach loop as well

Comment: Nah, I've been removing the foreach loop when removing the Console.write() line.  Failing to remove the foreach loop actually makes the code fail to even build.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, for anyone who later comes across this.  It looks like it was a timing issue.  bResult was returning as true because the transfer was a success, but the information wasn't actually making it into the byte array I was referencing with the GCHandle.

The solution was to force Winusb to transmit synchronously by changing the overlapped handle to a null pointer.  The WinUsb_ReadPipe line was changed to:

```
    Win32.WinUsb_ReadPipe(d._handle, _inPipe, pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject(), bufferlength, ref lengthtransferred, IntPtr.Zero);
```

And it works perfectly.

Inspired by [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/1a667575-82ab-497d-8498-d465592b4040/strange-receive-problem-using-winusb-under-net?forum=wdk)